# Nil on data request, problem with handling requests from REST API

Tags: swift

I'm trying to inflate my layout with data, it works but on some attempts user filed or comments field just have still nil and it fails. How can I can optimise the requests? I'm still beginner with swift and I cannot wrap my had around this.
The class that fails is the findUserById which does just what it is in the name. So find the user for specific id from the users list. But sometimes users are not yet initalized and the error with force unwraping is visible

```
 func findUserByUserId(UserId:Int) -> User{
        var userPlaceholder : User!
          for user in self.users {
              if(user.id == UserId){
                  userPlaceholder = user
              }
          }

        return userPlaceholder
      }
```

This is the function that I'm using for setting up the structure of the table cell

```
    private func fetchPost() {
        
        self.posts.forEach { (post) in
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async(group: dispatchGroup) {
                self.dispatchGroup.enter()
                
                self.postsCellViewModels.append(PostsCellViewModel(post: post, user: self.findUserByUserId(UserId: post.userId), comments: self.findCommensByPostId(PostId: post.id)))
                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            os_log("PostsViewModel -> Finished fetching posts")
            self.isLoading = false
            self.reloadData?()
        }
```

And this is function for fetchingUsers from API, i have the same for posts and comments, data is taken from JSONPlaceholderAPI

```
 func fetchUsers(){
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        os_log("PostsViewModel -> Starting users fetching")
        if let client = client as? JSONPlaceholderClient {
            self.isLoading = true
            let endpoint = JsonPlaceHolderEndpoint.users
            client.fetchUsers(with: endpoint) { (either) in
                switch either {
                    case .success(let users):
                        self.users = users
                        os_log("PostsViewModel -> Ended users fetching")
                        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                    case .error(let error):
                        self.showError?(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear how the `DispatchGroup` `enter` and `leave` calls are related to each other. In the `fetchPost()` method both calls make no sense anyway because `append` is synchronous. And you can replace the entire body of `findUserByUserId` with `return users.first {$0.id == UserId}`.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the tips, yeah right now I clean it all up, and it's working pretty good right now. It was a huge mess there.